# Get php from the same folder

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

**func.js**:

```
$.get(
    "test.php",
    {id: theid}, 
    function(data){...}
)
```

My `test.php` and `func.js` files are inside `/scripts/data/` folder, full url for php is http://site.com/scripts/data/test.php

**How do I get php file without usage of relative path?**

This script should work on other domains too.

Thanks.

Comment: You should definitely improve your question. It is not entirely clear (to me) what exactly you want. I think I got it now after some hard thinking, but your question doesn’t make it easy to understand. Are you asking on how to use the URI when your URI is in a separate JS file but used at different levels of other scripts/pages?

Comment: @Kissaki question is improved, thanks

Comment: I still don’t get it. `How do I get php file inside the same folder, where current js file is placed?` You can put the PHP file there via FTP, SSH, file-explorer … But I don’t think that’s what you’re trying to ask here …

Comment: @Kissaki haha my english is crappy, now its clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a relative path:

```
$.get(
    "/scripts/data/test.php",
    {id: theid}, 
    function(data){...}
)
```

Comment: Which will only work (the way you posted) if the folder structure under the domain is actually the same. If the scripts are put into other subdirs it won’t work anymore with the absolute-relative (beginning with `/`) URI.

Comment: @jAndy : I just edited your question. While it answered the OP's question, there was still a mistake the OP made : `{id = theid}` is wrong. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: id is $_GET[id], and theid is a js variable, there is nothing wrong on that line

Comment: @Happy: sure there is. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) : it's `variable name: variable value` and not `variable name = variable value`

Comment: @Shikiryu ahh, you are true, thats a typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative paths in the get, such as "/scripts/data/test.php". 
See the get documentation for jquery here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
The example there uses 'ajax/test.html'.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For URLs you have 3 options.

- absolute URIs (with domain)
- absolute relative URIs (without domain, but the full path; these start with `/`)
- relative URIs

If your problem is that the places (URI paths) you use your JS script which is in a separate JS file varies but you don’t want to use absolute URIs nor absolute relative URIs then you should improve your JS scripts design.

You should make the script itself path-independent and the webpage using the JS script should pass the path to a root folder or the scripts/data folder, or some other base-path of your application to the JS script.